# Writing methods of encrypting and decrypting text in a java project

Tags: java, methods, parameters, return, do-while

Having issues with getting my code to function correctly the first part works okay it encrypts the the inputted code and prints the result however when the function gets to the method shift alphabet I'm greeted with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end -1, length 0.
```

Can someone explain to me where I have gone wrong in my project as I am struggling here.

Code is below.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void  main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
        String encryptedText;
        int encryptedNumber;
        int length;

        System.out.println("Please input text to encrypt");
        encryptedText = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter a number for encryption amount");
        encryptedNumber = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter a length for your segment");
        length = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Thank you for your input");

        String compressedvalue = encryptString(encryptedText,encryptedNumber,length);
        System.out.println(" Your encrypted value is:" + compressedvalue);

        String decryptedText = ungroupify(compressedvalue);
        System.out.println("The decryption algorithm produced: "  + decryptedString(decryptedText,encryptedNumber));
        System.out.println("Thank you");

        normalizeText(""  );
    }


    // Part 1 Normalized Method to convert all letter to uppercase and removing all special characters and placing it into String codey.
    public static String normalizeText (String codey){

        System.out.println(codey.replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "").toUpperCase());

        System.out.println(codey);
        obify("");
        return normalizeText(codey);

    }

    public static String obify(String input){
        String obifiledInput="";
        char[] vowels={'A','E','I','O','U','Y'};
        for (int i=0;i<input.length();i++){
            boolean flagVowelNotHave=true;
            for(int j=0;j<vowels.length;j++){
                if (input.charAt(i)==vowels[j]){
                    obifiledInput+=("OB"+input.charAt(i));
                    flagVowelNotHave=false;
                }
            }
            if(flagVowelNotHave)obifiledInput+=input.charAt(i);
        }
        ceasarify("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", 26);

        return obifiledInput;

    }

    public static String ceasarify(String a, int n){
        String letterIndex = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" ;
        String returnString = "";

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < a.length(); cnt++) {
            char oLetter = a.charAt(cnt);
            int oIndex = letterIndex.indexOf(oLetter);
            int nIndex = oIndex + n;
            if (nIndex >= 0) {
                if (nIndex > 25) {
                    while (nIndex > 25) { nIndex -= 26; }
                }
            }
            else {
                while (nIndex < 0) { nIndex += 26; }
            }
            returnString = returnString + letterIndex.charAt(nIndex);
        }
        groupify( "", 26 );
        return returnString;

    }

    public static String groupify( String p, int f){
        int newy = p.length();
        String segmented = "";
        int bigLength = newy % f;

        for (int chop = 0; chop < newy; chop += f) {
            if (chop + f > newy) {
                segmented = segmented + p.substring(chop, newy);
                for (int x = 0; x < bigLength; x++) {
                    segmented = segmented + "x";
                }
            }
            else { segmented = segmented + p.substring(chop, chop + f) + " "; }
        }


        if (bigLength == 0) { segmented = segmented.substring(0,segmented.length() - 1); }

        shiftAlphabet(0);
        return segmented;
    }

    public static String shiftAlphabet(int shift) {
        int start = 0;
        if (shift < 0) {
            start = (int) 'Z' + shift + 1;
        } else {
            start = 'A' + shift;
        }
        String result = "";
        char currChar = (char) start;
        for(; currChar <= 'Z'; ++currChar) {
            result = result + currChar;
        }
        if(result.length() < 26) {
            for(currChar = 'A'; result.length() < 26; ++currChar) {
                result = result + currChar;
            }
        }

        encryptString("",26,25);
        return result;
    }

    public static String encryptString(String code, int shifty, int big) {

        String ntext = normalizeText(code);
        String ctext = ceasarify(ntext,shifty);
        String gtext = groupify(ctext,2 );

        return gtext;
    }

    private static String decryptedString (String decryptedText, int encryptedNumber) {
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        encryptedNumber = encryptedNumber * -1; //Reverse the value.
        String bigText = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < decryptedText.length(); i++) {
            int oldText = alphabet.indexOf(decryptedText.charAt(i));
            int newText = oldText + encryptedNumber;

            // Wrap if longer/shorter than alphabet.
            if (newText < 0) { while(newText < 0) { newText += 26; } }
            else if (newText > 25) { while(newText > 25) { newText -= 26; } }

            bigText = bigText + alphabet.charAt(newText);
        }
        return bigText;
    }

    private static String ungroupify (String compressedvalue) {
        compressedvalue = compressedvalue.replace("x", ""); //Remove space-filling x's
        compressedvalue = compressedvalue.replace(" ", ""); //Remove spaces.
        return compressedvalue;
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging?

Comment: Also, would it be possible to share the stacktrace? The exception can shed some light as to why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

The firsts parameter you pass in for `groupify` is "".

[image]

When the `groupify` method is invoked, the `for` loop is skipped and `segmented.substring(0, 0-1);` function throws `IndexOutofBound` exception. 
[image]

Comment: [Don't post images of code.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)